# distribution of the indicator function of poisson

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, poisson-distribution

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be independent random variables with poisson distribution

Given indicator function 
$$ U_i=\left\{
\begin{aligned}
1 && X_1 \ = 0\\
0 && X_1 >0

\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

What is the distribution of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n U_i?$

Comment: Shouldn't $U_i=1$ if $X_i=0$ (not $X_1=0$) and $U_i=0$ if $X_i>0$?

Answer (score 2):

The distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^nU_i$ is the [Binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters $n$ and $p=\Pr\{X_1=0\}=\frac{\lambda^0e^{-\lambda}}{0!}=e^{-\lambda}$ since $U_1,\ldots,U_n$ are independent and identically distributed Bernoulli random variables.